# Starbound fails to start (Linux)

Tags: steam, linux, starbound

When I start Starbound the window asking to launch client or server pops up and when I answer client, the sidebar says "Running" then flashes "Syncing" then nothing. When Steam is launched from terminal, this is outputted:

```
Game update: AppID 211820 "Starbound", ProcID 28390, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
[Info] Application: Initializing SDL
[Info] Application: startup...
[Info] Root: Preparing Root...
[Info] Root: Done preparing Root.
[Info] Client Version 1.0.5 (linux x86_64) Source ID: 7d4a2bbba04d43bd7f43f0ca940db23b2187edc1 Protocol: 724
[Info] Root: Scanning for asset sources in directory '../assets/'
[Info] Root: Scanning for asset sources in directory '../mods/'
[Warn] Root: Unrecognized file in asset directory 'mods_go_here', skipping
[Info] Root: Detected asset source named 'base' at '../assets/packed.pak'
[Info] Root: Detected unnamed asset source at '../assets/user'
[Info] Loading assets from: '../assets/packed.pak'
[Info] Loading assets from: '../assets/user'
Generating new string page texture 113: 8x256, total string texture memory is 4.61 MB
[Info] Assets digest is 835de2a06240fd303c5cfc854388f3b67407dac8e006f903343715672b0705a3
[Info] Root: Loaded Assets in 0.673758 seconds
[Info] Application: Initializing SDL Video
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[Error] Fatal Error: Segfault Encountered!
./starbound(_ZN4Star10fatalErrorEPKcb+0x43) [0xa11063]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354a0) [0x7f62df4564a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12960) [0x7f62dff11960]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x126) [0x7f62dd78e206]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1(glXMakeCurrentReadSGI+0x1b2) [0x7f62e036a4d2]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xbc978) [0x7f62e08e9978]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xbcc96) [0x7f62e08e9c96]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xaede0) [0x7f62e08dbde0]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0xafc84) [0x7f62e08dcc84]
/home/mitchell/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0(+0x1744f) [0x7f62e084444f]
./starbound(_ZN4Star11SdlPlatformC2ESt10unique_ptrINS_11ApplicationESt14default_deleteIS2_EENS_10StringListE+0x1b8) [0x1224048]
./starbound(_ZN4Star18runMainApplicationESt10unique_ptrINS_11ApplicationESt14default_deleteIS1_EENS_10StringListE+0x3f) [0x12217af]
./starbound(main+0x457) [0x8e85f7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f62df441830]
./starbound() [0x8f59fc]
Aborted (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 211820 "Starbound", ProcID 28390 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.Generating new string page     texture 115: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
```

I have tried everything I have found. My system certainly meets specifications, and I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The odd part is that if I choose to run the server, everything works (note: I haven't had somebody try to connect), and if I run using run-starbound.sh everything works fine as well. This makes me think there is a problem with Steam, not Starbound.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try searching for specific errors in that data log, like `LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32)` or `libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so`

Comment: Mass posting error logs with little or no research effort is unlikely to get attention here. Try to narrow down your question a bit

Comment: @ThePickleTickler thanks for the hint about noveau... I was resarching segfault and coming up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with libstdc++.so.6 this can be fixed by preloading it when launching steam. This command should be used when launching steam.
`LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam`

To make this easier put that command in a bash script of some kind.